# How to find distance (in ft) between two adjacent points in a GPS trajectory dataset?

Tags: python, distance

I need to find the distance between two gps trajectories, from US 101 dataset, which covers totally 2000ft distance.

```
"Vehicle ID","Frame ID","Total Frames","Global Time","Local X","Local Y","Global X","Global Y","V_Len","V_Width","V_Class","V_Vel","V_Acc","Lane_ID","Pre_Veh","Fol_Veh","Spacing","Headway"

2,13,437,1118846980200,16.467,35.381,6451137.641,1873344.962,14.5,4.9,2,40.00,0.00,2,0,0,0.00,0.00
2,14,437,1118846980300,16.447,39.381,6451140.329,1873342.000,14.5,4.9,2,40.00,0.00,2,0,0,0.00,0.00
2,15,437,1118846980400,16.426,43.381,6451143.018,1873339.038,14.5,4.9,2,40.00,0.00,2,0,0,0.00,0.00
2,16,437,1118846980500,16.405,47.380,6451145.706,1873336.077,14.5,4.9,2,40.00,0.00,2,0,0,0.00,0.00
2,17,437,1118846980600,16.385,51.381,6451148.395,1873333.115,14.5,4.9,2,40.00,0.00,2,0,0,0.00,0.00
```

But when I am trying to find the distance between two adjacent points of the same vehicle, Its giving in more than 20 kms..

```
import math
def distance(origin, destination):
lat1, lon1 = origin
lat2, lon2 = destination
radius = 3959 * 5280 # km
dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) \
    * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
d = radius * c
return d
lat1 = 16.467; lat2 = 16.447; long1 = 35.381; long2 = 39.381;
print( distance((lat1, long1), (lat2, long2)) )
```

Can any you help me to find the distance between two adjacent trajectories
I need to segregate the dataset into subsections covering 200ft distance each..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure those coordinates are latitude and longitude?

I am not familiar with the dataset you are using. However, if I am not mistaken, [this](https://data.transportation.gov/Automobiles/Next-Generation-Simulation-NGSIM-Vehicle-Trajector/8ect-6jqj) is it. And the documentation clearly states about Local X (my italics):

> Lateral (X) coordinate of the front center of the vehicle *in feet* with respect to the left-most edge of the section in the direction of travel.

(and something similar for Local Y).

Comment: Then how can I find actual latitude and longitude... Actual link to download dataset is https://github.com/Atcold/pytorch-PPUU              my dataset is US 101 trajectory from 7:50am -8:05am

Comment: Do you *need* latitude and longitude? If I am not mistaken,  the coordinates are in a cartesian system in feet, so you can compute distances by simply using Pythagoras' theorem.

Comment: I need to split the data set into 200ft segment for analysis.

Comment: But why do you need latitude and longitude for that, when you already have coordinates in feet?

Comment: Yes @Ture Palsson, I realize that its possible to find the Cartesian distance between two points as per your suggestion... Kindly help me to subdivide my dataset into sections, whereas each section covers only 200ft

Comment: Then ask a new question about that, rather than commenting on this one.